# Getting gitHub change history

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-for-mac

I am trying, with no success, to find a way to get change history for a master branch.

I am trying to check for the top 10 files that changes have been made in, inside a defined timeline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the end, I extracted it to a CSV file and sorted by changed values.

This is how I solved the problem....

```
git diff $(git rev-list -n1 --before="1 week ago" master) --histogram --stat >file.csv
```